# Gulp. При создании const gulp = require('gulp'); выдается ошибка: Unresolved function or method require()

Tags: gulp, require

Gulp. При создании const  gulp = require('gulp'); выдается ошибка: Unresolved function or method require().

Поставил gulp cli глобально и gulp глобально и локально, а так же инициализировал проект npm init. Далее создал gulp.js и в нем const  gulp = require('gulp'); IDE подчеркивает require и пишет: Unresolved function or method require(). 
Подскажите что еще нужно установить или прописать.

Comment: Ну расскажите IDE, что у вас nodejs, а не абстрактный javascript

Answer (score 0):

у меня такая же проблема была, помог этот пост https://stackoverflow.com/a/35893441/6792608 в idea вот такую галку поставить надо [image: введите сюда описание изображения]